# Giving users roles in a C# WPF, MySQL app?

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my first project in WPF.  My goal is to build a template project that can be duplicated and reused again.

The goal is to build a Central Dashboard with permissions for each page/element in the application, with a login form.
For login and access to different elements of the app, I would like to assign each page a permission_id in the code.  Then i want those permissions given to roles and the roles given to user_id.

I have attached an image of the database tables.

Here are my questions:

**Q1: How can I link the tables in the database together?**

**Q2: What is the safest method to connect to a MySQL database in WPF?**

**Q3: What would i need to do, to show online users to everyone logged into the app?**

[image: SQL Table Design and Vision]

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Not really sure what you mean, the tables are linked already.

Q2: The safest method would be to create an API and have your WPF app consume that. Accessing the database directly from WPF app is not a good idea, since you're giving your connection string away.

Q3: It'd also be in your API logic, but the simplest way I think is simply to track users that make request and store them in-memory. These "tokens" would need to have some expiry date and refreshing mechanism, and you'd have to remove users whose tokens have expired from the list.